# Sum of the Hyperharmonic\Over-harmonic Series under $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for $p=2$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

For $n \geq 5$ prime number, calculate the sum of:
$$1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$$
under $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

I figured it's the hyperharmonic\over-harmonic series,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^{-2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac {1}{i^2}$$

But how am I to solve it for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ under $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: By $\Bbb{Z}_n$ do you mean the n-adic integers?

Comment: What does $1/2^2$ mean in $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: @LokiClock, I it means the $Modulo\space n$ field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I'm not sure, $0.25 = -(3.75)$?

Comment: @Georgey Could be, but that's usually $\Bbb{Z}/(n)$ or $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. And because there's no homomorphism from the rational numbers to the cyclic fields, it affects how the fractions are supposed to be interpreted.

Comment: @LokiClock, I understand what you're saying but I don't know what to answer as I just copied the question and added my thoughts about it. I'm not educated enough to answer you.

Comment: It would explain why the index goes up to where it does.

Comment: No. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are $\overline{0}$,$\overline{1}$, $\overline{2}$ and $\overline{3}$. None of these have the property that multiplying them by four would give $\overline{1}$. So no element that could be calles $1/2^2$ is available. Which is why I think the sum doesn't exist when $n=4$. It does exist, when $n$ is a prime, because the above problem doesn't appear. But in that case it is easy to see that the sum is always zero.

Comment: Oh god I forgot to mention that $n \geq 5$

Comment: The same problem appears with $1/2^2$ appears for all even $n$. Also the problem with $1/3^2$ is there whenever $n$ is divisible by three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n$ is prime, $\Bbb{Z}/(n)$ is a field and has fractions for every element. Being divisible means there can't be two elements with the same inverse. Every element's inverse's square appears in the sum, therefore every element's square appears in the sum. So the sum of squares of inverses can be stated as simply the sum of squares in the field, however many times that square is used.

I suppose for other $n$ you have to prove that every square is in the group of units.

EDIT: Per Jyrki's comment, if $a$ is not a unit, $1\not\in(a) \implies 1 \not \in (a^2) \implies a$ is not a unit. Therefore all elements must be units if all squares are units, therefore $\Bbb{Z}/(n)$ must be a field, therefore $n$ must be prime.

Comment: This is exactly the way to show that the sum is zero, when $n$ is an odd prime: you could easily show that each square is used exactly twice, and use the formula for geometric sums (the square of primitive root as a ratio). But how could a square of a non-unit be a unit?

Comment: Why can you tell that if every element's inverse's square appears in the sum $\Rightarrow$ every element's square appears in the sum?

Comment: @Georgey, because $\{1^2, 2^2, \ldots, (n-1)^2\}$ and $\{1^{-2}, 2^{-2},\ldots, (n-1)^{-2}\}$ each contain the same $n-1$ elements (i.e. everything but 0), so taking a reciprocal is a permutation.